# Coldfusion CreateObject from different directory

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfc

My directory structure:

1. Com.Lib.db ( All db cfcs )
2. Com.Lib.search ( All search cfcs )
3. Com.Lib.utils ( All utils cfcs )

If I'm creating a normal object of (db) directory from webroot directory.

Example:

```
Createobject("component", "Com.Lib.db.mycfcA");
```

If I'm in (db) directory creating object

Example:
    Createobject("component", "mycfcA");

This is a normal case. In my case, I want to create an object from db directory to Utils OR Search. When I try to give full path for example:
If I'm in the db directory, trying to create an object of myUtils.cfc, in the (Utils) Directory.

```
Createobject("component", "Com.Lib.Utils. myUtils");
```

Comment: you might need a mapping. In your `Application.cfc` something like <cfset `this.mappings["com"]="c:\inetpub\wwroot\website1">

Comment: The component path `Com.Lib...` is relative to the root path (`/`) of your application. If the physical path is not in the same directory as your application, you need a mapping.

Comment: thanks for quick reply I did  but still not working

Comment: Application.cfc  <cfset this.rootDir = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) /> 
 <cfset this.mappings[ "com" ] = "#this.rootDir#com" />

Comment: <cfset cleanUp = createobject("component","Com.Lib.Utils.myUtils")>

Comment: Do you see any error message?

Comment: ERROR : invalid component definition, can't find component [com.Lib.Utils.myUtils]    -------------------- IM DOING SOMETHING WRONG ??

Comment: Having periods in your folder names certainly don't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate the relative path finding of components, here is an example:

Your web application's is like:

```
/wwwroot/your-app/Application.cfc
/wwwroot/your-app/index.cfm
/wwwroot/your-app/images/example.jpg
```

You have a virtual host (`www.your-app.com`) that points to:

```
/wwwroot/your-app/
```

This is your root. ColdFusion will resolve `/` physically as `/wwwroot/your-app/` (default root mapping).

Invoking a component like:

```
createObject("component", "Com.Lib.Utils.myUtils")
```

will now check for the existence of the file, i.e. initialize the component:

```
/wwwroot/your-app/Com/Lib/Utils/myUtils.cfc
```

If your CFCs are not present in this structure, you need to define a custom mapping for them.
Custom mappings are defined in the constructor of your `Application.cfc`.
So let's assume your CFCs are in the following directory:

```
/wwwroot/my-cfcs/Com/Lib/Utils/
```

Now you would create a mapping for them like:

```
<!--- Application.cfc --->
<cfcomponent>

    <cfset THIS.mappings["utils"] = "/wwwroot/my-cfcs/Com/Lib/Utils/">

</cfcomponent>
```

To invoke the components, you can now refer to the mapped component path like:

```
createObject("component", "utils.myUtils")
```

And this will check for the existence of the file, i.e. initialize the component:

```
/wwwroot/my-cfcs/Com/Lib/Utils/myUtils.cfc
```

Comment: I don't think you anyone can give better then this detailed solution.  I don't know why it is not working. im using [fedora -- Lucee 4.5.1.022] I have no idea why it is not working. Do you think it could be because of lucee or fedora???

Comment: Application.cfc 
<cfset this.mappings["com"] = "/opt/lucee/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/MyApp/Com/" />                                              Test.cfm  
<cfset cleanUp = createobject("component","Com.Lib.Utils.myUtils")>

Comment: Ohhhhh... Working now I found the problem I was defining mapping in "onstartapplication" ... just looking code line by line....